# Scroll by clicking and dragging inside div instead of clicking scrollbar

Tags: css

This CSS is for a DIV in an MVC2 application.  The overflow:auto line adds a horizontal scrollbar to the div which is needed since the table in the div is very wide and extends past the edge of the page.

```
#main
{
    padding: 30px 30px 15px 30px;
    overflow:auto;/* this adds horizontal scroll*/
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    _height: 1px; /* only IE6 applies CSS properties starting with an underscore */
}
```

Eventually there are going to be multiple tables stacked and the horizontal scroll bar is going to be below the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way to allow the users to click and drag inside the div to make it scroll instead of actually having to click the scrollbar?

Answer (score 28):

A very minimized **JQuery** approach to apply this functionality:

```
$.fn.attachDragger = function(){
    var attachment = false, lastPosition, position, difference;
    $( $(this).selector ).on("mousedown mouseup mousemove",function(e){
        if( e.type == "mousedown" ) attachment = true, lastPosition = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
        if( e.type == "mouseup" ) attachment = false;
        if( e.type == "mousemove" && attachment == true ){
            position = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
            difference = [ (position[0]-lastPosition[0]), (position[1]-lastPosition[1]) ];
            $(this).scrollLeft( $(this).scrollLeft() - difference[0] );
            $(this).scrollTop( $(this).scrollTop() - difference[1] );
            lastPosition = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
        }
    });
    $(window).on("mouseup", function(){
        attachment = false;
    });
}
```

To apply it utilize:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#divToScroll").attachDragger();
});
```

Comment: This works beautifully, thanks man. The only issue is that the text gets highlighted if you move your mouse over it, but that can be solved in a couple different ways.

Comment: @ScottM yeah the route I went is via CSS, just disable highlighting.  If you want your users to be able to highly, you can just swap a "active" class that includes no highlighting.

Comment: I need to use `$(this).on("mousedown....` and not `$( $(this).selector ).on("mousedown....` to make it working... why do you use the `.selector`?

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier originally designed to hook to $.fn prototype.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement three consecutive mouse event handlers in javascript for this:

1. The mousedown handler should trigger a drag start by enabling the mousemove event handler (see 2)
2. The mousemove handler should map the vertical mouse position to the scrollTop property of the div
3. The mouseup handler should trigger a drag stop by disabling the mousemove event handler

Note that I don't think this is good user interface design: you're basically removing the ability to select text inside this div. Besides, the user can scroll using the mouse wheel, so I don't see the need for this.

Comment: how do you scroll horizontally with the mouse wheel?

Comment: My bad, forgot that it was a horizontal scrollbar (in that case replace the vertical part in my answer with horizontal). I still think just using the scrollbar is enough though. The text selecting problem still applies, and second, people are used to scroll bars, even horizontal ones. If you can justify a horizontal scroll bar, eg when you have a table with many columns, it is absolutely justified to have a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: This question is almost 5 years old now, but you can scroll horizontally with just a mouse wheel using Shift+Scroll in all modern browsers.

Comment: Years later, this functionality is fairly common and provided by libraries such as "dragscroll", https://www.npmjs.com/package/dragscroll, and its variants for either React or Angular (https://github.com/bfwg/ngx-drag-scroll), etc.. @PeterKruithof makes a valid argument that the developer should consider before implementation. Peter's point is well-taken that if copying data is of concern, a workaround method for the end-user to extract data should be provided (i.e. provide an export function for a drag-scrolled table, etc.)